# Windows SSD won't boot after I used it in a USB enclosure with an Android phone

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, ssd, partition-recovery

I ran into an issue with a desktop folder on my Windows laptop that I can't delete or rename no matter what. I've seen this issue a few times over the years, but the typical ways to get around it just won't work for some reason. (I transferred it from my ftp without noticing the folder name starts with a bracket and ends with a space... and now I'm stuck with it.) I tried a few system restore points and they all worked, but the folder was always still there.

So I took out the SSD and put it into a USB enclosure so I could attach it to a different Windows laptop. But I still wasn't able to delete or rename the folder. I put it back in my laptop and booted Windows back up; back to square one.

Remembering that I could also use external storage with my phone, I once again took the SSD out of my laptop and put it back into the USB enclosure. I thought maybe the Android OS would allow me to rename or delete it, but I was wrong. Just like Windows, it told me it couldn't find the folder whenever I tried to do either.

I figured I was back to square one again, but I moved the SSD back into its laptop and now Windows won't boot! I put it back in the enclosure and while using Android, everything is still there and accessible. But when I plug it into a different Windows PC, it's got issues. It shows up as drive D: but it's inaccessible through Explorer. Disk Management sees it, but says the main partition is raw and not ntfs. I checked out a file recovery tool and everything is easily there, but I don't want to go that route. I just want to be able to boot back into Windows. I've never seen anything like this and my search attempts have come up empty.

I know Android has a habit of adding folders to external storage, but does it also do some kind of formatting that makes a Windows drive unbootable? More importantly, is there any way to reverse this change so that I can boot back into Windows?

Comment: You will need to format the disk and reinstall Windows. Save your data using your file recovery tool.

Comment: Do you know what specifically caused this or why the drive isn't recoverable?

Comment: I don't know exactly what Android does to the disk, but this the second case I encounter here where this happened.